# Why can't I use LINQ's First/FirstOrDefault method in OData?

Tags: linq, odata

I can do the following:

`container.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "Omar").FirstOrDefault()`

but

`container.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == "Omar")`

returns a `NotSupportedException (The method 'FirstOrDefault' is not supported.)`.

Since these are essentially the same, why is it no supported?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The LINQ Translation engine used by the OData provider doesn't handle every scenario.

While these are logically the same, the expression for each must be generated to build the query string.  The engine doesn't support the second form.

Comment: You have to use where before FirstOrDefault. e.g. container.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "Omar").FirstOrDefault();